# How to draw a flowchart in Enterprise Architect?

Tags: flowchart, enterprise-architect

Does anyone know any tutorials on how to draw a flowchart in EA? I'm having problems with using connectors. How do I connect it without another connector if possible?

Answer (score 11):

First check that you are really drawing a flowchart diagram - it should be this one: insert diagram->Strategic Modeling->Flow Chart.

Some tutorial can be found on the sparx webpage: http://www.sparxsystems.com/downloads/quick/strategic_modeling_with_enterprise_architect.pdf

Answer (score 4):

How to make a flow chart :

1.Go to "project Browser"(its in the right side of the tool ) and select "new model from pattern".
2.Select Strategic Modelling (a window with flow chart option will pop up )
3.Select Flow chart.

Connectors :

U can easily connect two Nodes.click on ----> and then the first box ...u get a dotted line drag it till second box done.
TO Bend the connectors:select the connector, right click on the connector and click on Bend Line at Cursor.now SLide the cursor to bend line to the extent u want.

I am too using the tool for first time and had this problem of Bending the connectors .Hope this what u were expecting.

Tutorial Link By Meson is good enough:-) Thanks